# Proper subsets with the null set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

According to one of my graded homework assignment that was returned to me, $\{\emptyset\} \subset \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$, but $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \not\subset \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$. Can someone explain this to me? They were two separate questions: I got the first one right, but I said that $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \subset \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$

Comment: Is there any chance of a misread $\notin$ as in $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \notin \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{\{\emptyset\}\} \subset \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ is correct too.

Comment: Awesome! Take that prof. Thanks.